# SQL count specific items for a cutomer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to render the following table in order to know how many burgers a customer has payed

> Customer | Burger 1 Quantity | Burger 2 Quantity|

I have two tables :

- customer table : with CustomerID, Name
- Transaction order : with TransactionOrderID CustomerID and BurgerCode

I have 6 burger code, for each one I need to add a column, what is the best way to do that?

Comment: with a `pivot` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: can you please post sample data

Comment: What are you using to render your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a pivot you could try something like this.

```
   WITH cte AS
   ( 
   SELECT 
       CustomerID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BurgerCode LIKE 'BurgerCode1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Burger1Qty,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BurgerCode LIKE 'BurgerCode2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Burger2Qty,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BurgerCode LIKE 'BurgerCode3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Burger3Qty,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BurgerCode LIKE 'BurgerCode4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Burger4Qty,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BurgerCode LIKE 'BurgerCode5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Burger5Qty,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BurgerCode LIKE 'BurgerCode6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Burger6Qty
    FROM TransactionOrders
    GROUP BY CustomerID
    )
    SELECT c.*, ct.Name CustomerName FROM cte c JOIN CustomerTable ct ON ct.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```